# Office 365 Groups vs Security Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory

I understand the purpose of Office 365 Groups. However, even without any Office 365 services, it appears that Office 365 Groups have some advantages like soft delete and expiration.

Is there any reason NOT to use the "Office 365 Group" type when creating new groups in Azure AD?

Comment: Well, for one thing you can have an AAD tenant which is not connected to an O365 tenant. In that case security groups are the only option.

Comment: @juunas this is not accurate. Even for a brand new AAD tenant, I see the option of "Office 365" when creating a new AAD group, it is part of the "Type" drop down.